# Count the different positions reached in a cycle of permutations

Tags: python, algorithm, time-limit-exceeded, combinatorics

I have come across a problem on cyclic permutations. It is about swapping numbers around.

It starts out with input N < 100,000 which makes the first N natural numbers as orders: 1 2 3 ... N-1 N

Then we get the next input K < 200,000 as the period

Next N input lines are the swaps:

For example, the input is

```
5 4
1 3
1 2
2 3
2 4
```

There are 5 numbers and the swap period is 4. The first swap switches number at position 1 with position 3. The second swap is between position 1 and position 2. The third swap is between position 2 and position 3. The fourth swap is between 2 and 4. K+1th swap is same as first. K+2th swap is same as second. Etc.

The simulation for this is:

```
1 2 3 4 5
3 2 1 4 5 
2 3 1 4 5 
2 1 3 4 5 
2 4 3 1 5 
3 4 2 1 5 
4 3 2 1 5 
4 2 3 1 5 
4 1 3 2 5 
3 1 4 2 5 
1 3 4 2 5 
1 4 3 2 5 
1 2 3 4 5
```

We can see that the original number at position 3 can go to positions 1, 2, and 3. The original number at position 1 can go to positions 1, 2, 3, 4. The original number at position 2 can go to positions 1, 2, 3, 4. The original number at position 4 can go to positions 1, 2, 3, 4. The original number at position 5 can go to positions 5.

Position 1 goes to 4 positions. Position 2 goes to 4 positions. Position 3 goes to 3 positions. Position 4 goes to 4 positions. Position 5 goes to 1 position.

Given that each output line is represented by y, the output is the number of totals positions the yth original position goes to. Output for this example is:

```
4
4
3
4
1
```

The memory limit is 256MB and the time limit is 2 seconds for noninterpreted languages such as C++ and 4 seconds for interpreted languages such as Java.

```
z, d = map(int, input().split())

S = []

pos = {}


for i in range(1, z+1):
  pos[i] = [i,]

permute = list(range(1, z+1))
for i in range(d):
  S.append(list(map(int, input().split())))


Flag = True

while Flag:
  Flag = False
  for i in S:
    if i[0] not in pos[permute[i[1]-1]]:
      Flag = True
      pos[permute[i[1]-1]].append(i[0])
    if i[1] not in pos[permute[i[0]-1]]:
      Flag = True
      pos[permute[i[0]-1]].append(i[1])
    permute[i[0]-1], permute[i[1]-1] = permute[i[1]-1], permute[i[0]-1]


for i in pos:
  print(len(pos[i]))
```

My solution takes too much space/time. Can you help me fix this?

I know this problem has DFS but I don't know what the graph to do DFS on looks like?

Comment: If this is a programming challenge please post the link.

Answer (score 2):

## Naming

The question starts off talking about `N` and `K`.  Your code begins with reading in `z` and `d`.  The question text is ready-made documentation for your code; use the same names for the variables!

`n, k = map(int, input().split())`

Guilty, I said `N` and `K` but used `n` and `k`.  PEP 8, the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://pep8.org) recommends using `snake_case` for variables.  So we should also change `S` and `Flag` to `s` and `flag`.

But ...  what is `flag`?  Obviously, it is a flag, but a flag for what?  Perhaps `changed` would be a better name; you are looping while a change was made in the previous iteration.

Similarly, `S` is your list of swaps.  Why not call it `swaps`?

## Don't relookup values

Python is an interpreted language.  It doesn't do any data-flow analysis to determine if the value of an expression will be used again.  It can't, since the meaning of operations can be changed on the fly.

In the `for i in S` loop, how many times is `i[0]` and `i[1]` used?  Six times each.  Each time, the interpreter looks up the object stored in `i`, and calls the `__getitem__` method to fetch the value.  Let's fix this by looking up the value only once, and storing the values in (say) `p` and `q`:

```py
    for p, q is swaps:
        if p not in pos[permute[q - 1]]:
            changed = True
            pos[permute[q - 1]].append(p)
        ...
```

That is immediately clearer.  No extra `[0]` and `[1]` to confuse the issue.

## Use O(1) lookups instead of O(K) searches

You're using `if thing not in container: container.append(thing)`.  This is a lot like a `set`.  A set can only contain one instance of an item.  But unlike a list, `if thing not in container` is O(1) on a set, where as the with a list, the entire list has to be searched to ensure the thing is not inside the list.

Two simple changes.  First, instead of `pos[i] = [i,]` (the comma is actually unnecessary), initialize it with `pos[i] = {i}`.  Second, instead of `.append()`, use `.add()` to add the value to the set.

Note: sets are more complex than lists.  This may actually slow things down and use more memory, if the number of things in the containers is small.  The sets gain their speed advantage when they contain many elements.  So profile this change, especially using larger problem sets.

## Explicit is better than implicit

```py
swaps = []
for i in range(k):
  swaps.append(list(map(int, input().split())))
```

What happens if an input line has more than two numbers?  The input will be split into whole bunch of terms, each term will be mapped (converted) to an integer, and stored as a list inside the swaps list!

Oops.

If the program crashes, it will happen well after this point in the code.

It is better to crash early.  You expect exactly two values.  Be explicit.

```py
swaps = []
for i in range(k):
  swaps.append(list(map(int, input().split(maxsplit=1))))
```

If given more than two numbers, say `12 23 34`, then `split` will return `"12"` and `"23 34"`, and `int("23 34")` will raise a `ValueError`.  The bug will be caught earlier.

## Map the problem to Python, if possible

Python uses 0-based indexing.  The problem uses 1-based indexing.  You can get rid of the `+1` in `range` statements, and `-1` in the solution code by mapping the problem into a more Pythonic version.

For example, instead of swapping numbers at positions `1` and `3`, we'll swap them at positions `0` and `2`.  This just requires adjusting the swap positions as we read them in:

```py
swaps = []
for i in range(k):
  p, q = map(int, input().split())
  swaps.append([p - 1, q - 1])
```

Note.  The explicit `maxsplit=1` went away because we are assigned the result of map to a tuple of two variables, which requires exactly two values.  Explicit is better than implicit ... especially when the it can be expressed implicitly!

## Reworked Code

```py
n, k = map(int, input().split())

pos = {}
for i in range(n):
  pos[i] = {i}

permute = list(range(n))

swaps = []
for i in range(k):
  p, q = map(int, input().split())
  swaps.append([p - 1, q - 1])

changed = True

while changed:
  changed = False
  for p, q in swaps:
    if p not in pos[permute[q]]:
      changed = True
      pos[permute[q]].add(p)
    if q not in pos[permute[p]:
      changed = True
      pos[permute[p]].add(q)
    permute[p], permute[q] = permute[q], permute[p]

for i in pos:  # Note: relies on ordered dictionary
  print(len(pos[i]))
```

## Algorithmic improvement

`1 2 3 4 5`

After one iteration of swaps, you end up with this:

`2 4 3 1 5`

We can see we have moved

- 1 -> 2, 2 -> 4, 4 -> 1.  (length 3)
- 3 -> 3
- 5 -> 5

The 1 visited locations 1, 3, 2 and 4.  The 2 visited locations 2, and 1.  The 4 visited locations 4 and 2.  On subsequent iterations, the 2 will have moved into the 1's starting position and will visit 1, 3, 2 and 4, and so on.  So we have 1, 2, and 4 all visiting locations 1, 2, and 3 and 4 ... for a total of 4 locations

3 will visit 3, 1, and 2 and return to 3.

5 stays at 5.

All that is required is one pass through the swaps array to determine which positions each starting point visits, and what ending position it will have.  From that, the "rings" can be determined.  All starting positions in each ring will visit all the locations visited by every position in the ring.

With only one pass through the swaps array required, we don't need to save the swaps into a `swaps` list; it can be processed on the fly.  This helps the solution stay within the memory constraint.

```py
n, k = map(int, input().split())

pos = [{i} for i in range(n)]
permute = list(range(n))

# Perform swaps, recording which values appear in which positions
for _ in range(k):
    p, q = map(int, input().split())
    p -= 1  
    q -= 1

    pos[permute[q]].add(p)
    pos[permute[p]].add(q)
    permute[p], permute[q] = permute[q], permute[p]

# Implementation of final steps left to student
```